# show rows with no data in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT PersonTotalHours.MA, PersonTotalHours.Year, PersonTotalHours.CalendarWeek,
PersonTotalHours.Hours, Person.Name, Person.Lastname 
FROM PersonTotalHours
INNER JOIN Person
ON PersonTotalHours.MA = Person.MA;
```

Which results in the following table:

```
  MA       Year    CalendarWeek    Hours    Name    Lastname
  aA       2000         5           53      aa        AA
  aA       2000         44          175     aa        AA
  ...      ...         ...          ...
  aA       2001         4           226     aa        AA
  aA       2001         12          87      aa        AA
  ...      ...         ...          ...
  bB       2000         1           189     bb        BB
  bB       2000         35          65      bb        BB
  ...      ...         ...          ...
```

as you can see, there is no data for some calendar weeks. Is there any way that I can have a row for all calendar weeks(1 to 53) and with hours=0 for the ones that don't exist now?

**Edit**
I have solve this temporarily by adding the missing row to the table. using a function that is called when the report opens. Still looking for a non-stupid solution.

Comment: @Snickbrack I've edited the tags.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: @Snickbrack for showing data in an access report.

Comment: why isn't this information in the question?

Comment: I want to know if this is possible in the query, instead of coding or other stuff.

Comment: You need a calendar help table to join.

Comment: @jarlh what is a calendar help?

Comment: A table storing all possible dates. Do an outer join.

Comment: The calendar weeks 1 to 53 exist in your table? for thous calendar weeks the hours are empty or zero? if the first one is a no, then i guess you should create a view for that query or a "script" that output your formated data...

Comment: @jarlh Is there a reason to not use a while/recursive cte so solve the problem?

Comment: @Cody360c, well, I suppose that can be done too. (I'm used to calendar tables... Old habits...)

Comment: @jarlh I don't have an issue with calendar tables (or helper tables) I was just curious if there was a reason not to use the other methods : )

Comment: @Cody360c: Access SQL doesn't support CTE.

Comment: @Andre Didn't know it was access.  Access tag was just added not too long ago and I must have missed Mary's comment saying "for showing data in an access report"

Answer (score 4):

Create a help table `Calendar`, storing all possible values. `RIGHT JOIN` it:

```
SELECT pth.MA, pth.Year, pth.CalendarWeek,
pth.Hours, p.Name, p.Lastname 
FROM PersonTotalHours pth
INNER JOIN Person p
    ON pth.MA = p.MA
RIGHT JOIN Calendar c
    ON pth.Year = c.Year AND pth.CalendarWeek = c.CalendarWeek
```

(Using table aliases to spare some typing.)

**EDIT:** MS Access query attempt, version 1:

```
SELECT pth.MA, pth.Year, pth.CalendarWeek,
pth.Hours, p.Name, p.Lastname 
FROM (PersonTotalHours pth
INNER JOIN Person p
    ON pth.MA = p.MA)
RIGHT JOIN Calendar c
    ON pth.Year = c.Year AND pth.CalendarWeek = c.CalendarWeek
```

**EDIT:** MS Access query attempt, version 2:

```
SELECT pth.MA, pth.Year, pth.CalendarWeek,
pth.Hours, p.Name, p.Lastname 
FROM calendar
    left join (PersonTotalHours pth
               INNER JOIN Person p ON pth.MA = p.MA)
    ON pth.Year = c.Year AND pth.CalendarWeek = c.CalendarWeek
```

Comment: Corrected. (Missed to remove semi-colon...) BTW, `YEAR` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, so perhaps you need to delimit that column as `"YEAR"`.

Comment: no, removed the colon myself, but still getting "Operator missing" error

Comment: And you have created that calendar table, with the columns year and CalendarWeek? (And inserted data into it.)

Comment: I did. now I get join expression not supported, after putting parantheses around first join.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? MS Access...?

Comment: Well, multiple joins is a bit special when using Access. I'll soon make an edit. Hopefully Access compatible.

Comment: now the error is "join expression not supported". and it's only the right join. with left join I don't get error but of course the result is not what I need to have.

Comment: Another attempt added, switched to left join.

Comment: `Year` and possibly `Name` are reserved words and may need `[]` around them.

Comment: @Andre, good point. Seems like OP already delimits those column names, since the left join executes (with wrong result...)

Comment: Still same error. I guess the problem is related to the fact that all Calendar weeks don't exist in the PersonTotalHours  table

Answer (score 0):

Please check this query.

```
select PersonTotalHours.MA,PersonTotalHours.YEAR,b.CalendarWeek, PersonTotalHours.Hours, '' Name, '' LastName from PersonTotalHours
right join (
select '' MA, 0 Year, no CalendarWeek, 0 Hours, '' Name, '' Lastname from (
select row_number() over(order by object_id) no from sys.all_objects
) a where no <= 53) b on b.CalendarWeek = Table_1.CalendarWeek
```

I am not joined person table.